# How do I convert this pyqt4 code to pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt

I am a beginner and need this code to work for PyQt5 and I cannot figure out how to do this. I have tried changing parts but it just crashes. It should be able to load a CSV file into a table widget as well as being able to save  the table into a CSV.

```
import csv

import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, fileName, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.fileName = fileName

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)

        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

        self.pushButtonLoad = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonLoad.setText("Load Csv File!")
        self.pushButtonLoad.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonLoad_clicked)

        self.pushButtonWrite = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonWrite.setText("Write Csv File!")
        self.pushButtonWrite.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonWrite_clicked)

        self.layoutVertical = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonLoad)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonWrite)

    def loadCsv(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, "rb") as fileInput:
            for row in csv.reader(fileInput):    
                items = [
                    QtGui.QStandardItem(field)
                    for field in row
                ]
                self.model.appendRow(items)

    def writeCsv(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, "wb") as fileOutput:
            writer = csv.writer(fileOutput)
            for rowNumber in range(self.model.rowCount()):
                fields = [
                    self.model.data(
                        self.model.index(rowNumber, columnNumber),
                        QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole
                    )
                    for columnNumber in range(self.model.columnCount())
                ]
                writer.writerow(fields)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonWrite_clicked(self):
        self.writeCsv(self.fileName)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonLoad_clicked(self):
        self.loadCsv(self.fileName)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow("/path/to/MyFile.csv")
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This uses a QTableView but I would like it to use a Widget instead. Have tried using QWidgets for pyqt5 but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `QTableView` is easier in this case. Try it:

```
#import sip
#sip.setapi('QString', 2)
#sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)
#from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
import csv
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, fileName, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.fileName = fileName

        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self)

        self.tableView = QTableView(self)

        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

        self.pushButtonLoad = QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonLoad.setText("Load Csv File!")
        self.pushButtonLoad.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonLoad_clicked)

        self.pushButtonWrite = QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonWrite.setText("Write Csv File!")
        self.pushButtonWrite.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonWrite_clicked)

        self.layoutVertical = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonLoad)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonWrite)

    def loadCsv(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, "r") as fileInput:                    # - "rb"
            for row in csv.reader(fileInput):    
                items = [
                    QStandardItem(field)
                    for field in row
                ]
                self.model.appendRow(items)

    def writeCsv(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, "w") as fileOutput:                   # - "wb"
            writer = csv.writer(fileOutput, lineterminator='\n')  # + lineterminator='\n'
            print('rowCount->', self.model.rowCount())
            for rowNumber in range(self.model.rowCount()):

                fields = [
                    self.model.data(
                        self.model.index(rowNumber, columnNumber),
                        Qt.DisplayRole
                    )
                    for columnNumber in range(self.model.columnCount())
                ]
                print('fields->', fields)
                writer.writerow(fields)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonWrite_clicked(self):
        self.writeCsv(self.fileName)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonLoad_clicked(self):
        self.loadCsv(self.fileName)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow("D:/_Qt/txt_csv.csv")
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**txt_csv.csv**

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

[image]

Comment: Run the program from the command line (CMD) and you should get an error in a specific line.

Comment: Ah okay, figured it out. Thanks this helps a lot. Just need to see if there's a way I can now use this data to perform calculations within my python GUI.